# merge more than 3 dictionaries with repeating keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have many dictionaries that I want to merge. Here is an example:

```
dic1 = {'celia' : [14,3]}
dic2 = {'celia' : [12,9], 'pierre' : [34,12]}
dic3 = {'celia' : [10,11], 'gustav' : [22]}
dic4 = {'pierre' : [9,21]}
```

And I would like the final result to look like:

```
dic = {'celia' : [14,3,12,9,10,11], 'pierre': [34,12,9,21], 'gustav' : [22]}
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: A MRE is a [MRE] that shows the problem with the code you've written to accomplish the task you set out to do. The input and expected output are not a MRE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict` from the `collections`  module. With this, you can specify a default data type for the dictionary, so when a key doesn't exist yet, it initializes it with an empty list. Here you can avoid checking if a key exists or not and just directly append it to the list.

Here's the code:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

dic1 = {'celia': [14, 3]}
dic2 = {'celia': [12, 9], 'pierre': [34, 12]}
dic3 = {'celia': [10, 11], 'gustav': [22]}
dic4 = {'pierre': [9, 21]}

def merge_dicts(*dicts):
    merged = defaultdict(list)
    for d in dicts:
        for key, value in d.items():
            merged[key].extend(value)
    return dict(merged)

result = merge_dicts(dic1, dic2, dic3, dic4)
print(result)
```

The function `merge_dicts` accepts any number of dictionaries as input and then merges them into the `merged` defaultdict and returns a normal dictionary at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is an algorithmic problem, which has many possible solutions. Here is one of them

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.target_result = {}

    def insert(self, d: dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k in self.target_result:
                self.target_result[k].extend(v)
            else:
                self.target_result[k] = v


dic1 = {'celia': [14, 3]}
dic2 = {'celia': [12, 9], 'pierre': [34, 12]}
dic3 = {'celia': [10, 11], 'gustav': [22]}
dic4 = {'pierre': [9, 21]}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    solution = Solution()
    for d in [dic1, dic2, dic3, dic4]:
        solution.insert(d)
        print(solution.target_result)
```

Comment: thanks for answering! the solution above was rather straightforward so I went with it